# Splunk join two query to based on result of first query

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-cloud

In Splunk query I have two query like below

Query 1- index=mysearchstring1
Result - employid =123

Query 2- index=mysearchstring2

Here I want to use employid=123 in my query 2 to lookup and return final result.

Is it possible in Splunk?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're looking for a subsearch.

```
index=mysearchstring2 [ search index=mysearchstring1 | fields employid | format ]
```

Splunk will run the subsearch first and extract only the employid field.  The results will be formatted into something like `(employid=123 OR employid=456 OR ...)` and that string will be appended to the main search before it runs.